# Disallowing user to view page

Tags: php

I'm trying to make my PHP page disallow viewing of the page unless your on a certain IP as viewed below. I'm not sure what to try as I haven't really been doing PHP for very long.

```
$clientip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$whitelistedip = 'realIPhere';

    if ($clientip == $whitelistedip) {
    echo "Welcome $clientip!";
    }
    
    if ($clientip !== $whitelistedip) {
     die("Access Denied");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you comparing the URL? If they're not on the whitelisted IP, just die.

Comment: `in_array($currentIp, $allowedIps) or die('Access denied.');`

Comment: This still doesn't deny access to the page, merely disable the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP checking bit does not seem to contain mistakes, except that if you only check it with `REMOTE_ADDR`, the check may fail in some cases, so refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php) question to implement a better method of checking the IP.

Also, unless you have defined them somewhere else, `REQUEST_URL` and `URL_OF_CURRENT_PAGE` are no valid variables of the `$_SERVER` environment. You could be looking into `REQUEST_URI`, which is indeed a valid one. You can consult them [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

I understand that you would like to only show the HTML page contents if the IP is whitelisted. You may do so using the below shown syntax:

```
<?php
$clientip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$whitelistedip = 'realIPhere';
?>

<?php if ($clientip == $whitelistedip) : ?>

<!-- Place all your HTML here, example: -->
<p>hi</p>

<?php else : ?>

<?php die("Access denied") ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

In the above case, the `<p>hi</p>` won't be displayed if the IP is not whitelisted. Instead of the `hi`, of course, you should put the actual contents of your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the test against `$URL_OF_CURRENT_PAGE` is failing.  I don't see why you have that anyway, are you only trying to block in the case that he's getting there directly? If I was coding this it would be somewhat simpler:

```
if ($clientip == $whitelistedip) {
    echo "Welcome $clientip!";
}
else {
    die ("Access Denied"); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, That ends the script but I'm trying to make it not make the page appear. Lets say its not the IP so the HTML doesn't appear and instead says something like access denied. https://imgur.com/a/xvKYMW1